# How to display an additional info popup next to the content assist popup in an Eclipse plugin?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, content-assist

I'm trying to implement my own content assist and I can't add a popup with additional information for every proposal I get in the content assist popup.

I tried using the following implementation, but it didn't worked:

```
public ICompletionProposal[] computeCompletionProposals(ITextViewer viewer, int documentOffset) {
    ICompletionProposal[] result= new ICompletionProposal[fgProposals.length];
    for (int i= 0; i < fgProposals.length; i++) {
        result[i]= new CompletionProposal(fgProposals[i], documentOffset, 0, fgProposals[i].length(), null, fgProposals[i], info, MessageFormat.format(JavaEditorMessages.getString("CompletionProcessor.Proposal.hoverinfo.pattern"), new Object[] { fgProposals[i]})); //$NON-NLS-1$
    }
    return result;
}
```

I also tried using Context Information, but I don't think it is what I'm looking for and also I couldn't display the Context Information and the Content Assist at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default `ContentAssistant` you need to call `setInformationControlCreator` to set the code used to create this additional information popup.

The usual way to do this in the `SourceViewerConfiguration` is:

```java
public IContentAssistant getContentAssistant(final ISourceViewer sourceViewer)
{
  final ContentAssistant assistant = new ContentAssistant();

  .. other setup ...

  assistant.setInformationControlCreator(getInformationControlCreator(sourceViewer));

  return assistant;
}
```